# How do I handle CSRF for Google Sign-In? (Using Python and Django)

Tags: javascript, python-3.x, django, google-cloud-platform, google-signin

I'm building a simple Login page using Python and Django. I want to give the users the choice to login using either the Django account or Google Sign-In.

I've build some simple HTML and functions to flow between 4 pages: `Main`, `login_success`,`logout_success` and `already_logged_in`

As far as I've understand, I've set up at the very least a button on my login page, with some relevant scripts.

So, then I deploy to my Google Cloud, access the site, see the button and click on it and it redirects me to a Google Sign-In page where I can choose my account. I click on the account and I get a `Forbidden: CSRF Error`.

Am I missing something?
I am not sure how to debug this.

This is my `Main` login HTML.(I'm not sure if the rest are needed to be shown?)

```
{% load i18n %}
{% block content %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<meta charset="UTF-8">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" media="all" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<head>

    <title>Google Signin Testing</title>
    <style>
    .left {
        float: left;
        width: 40%;
        padding-left:32%;
        padding-top:13%;
        height: 75%
        }
    .right {
        float: left;
        width: 40%;
        padding-top:5%;
        height: 100%
        }

    h1 {
        text-shadow: 2px 2px 2px #aaa;
        }

    h2.maintitle {
        padding-left:5%;
        font-variant: small-caps;
        font-size: 36px;'
        }

    </style>

    <script src="https://accounts.google.com/gsi/client" async defer></script>

    <script>
    function onSignIn(credentialResponse) {
        document.body.innerHTML = "Signed in";
    }
    </script>
</head>

<body>

    <div class='row' >
        <div class='container-fluid col-6 left' >
        </div>

        <div class='container-fluid col-6 right' >  

            <h1>{% trans 'Log-In' %}</h1>
            {% if request.user.is_authenticated %}
                <p>{% trans 'You are already logged in' %}, <a href="{% url 'login_success' %}">my homepage</a></p>
            {% else %}
                <form action="" method="post">
                    {% csrf_token %}

                    {% if form.non_field_errors %}
                        {% for x in form.non_field_errors %}
                            <text style="color:red; font-size:12px;" id='{{field.label}}'><b>{{x}}</b></text>
                            <p/>
                        {% endfor %}
                    {% endif %}

                    {% for field in form %}
                        <div class="fieldWrapper">
                            {{ field.label_tag }} {{ field }}
                            <br/>
                            {% for x in field.errors %}
                                <text style="color:red; font-size:12px;" id='{{field.label}}'><b>{{x}}</b></text>
                            {% endfor %}
                            <p/>
                        </div>
                    {% endfor %}

                    <input style='max-height:8vh;font-size:clamp(5px, 2.3vh, 30px);object-fit;' type="submit" value="Log In"></input>
                    <br/><br/>
                    
                    <!---div id="g_id_onload"
                         data-client_id="[Google Cloud ID]"
                         data-context="signin"
                         data-ux_mode="popup" /* popup */
                         data-login_uri="[Google Cloud URL]"
                         data-auto_prompt="false">
                    </div--->
                    
                    <div id="g_id_onload"
                         data-client_id="[Google Cloud ID]"
                         data-context="signin"
                         data-ux_mode="redirect"
                         data-login_uri="[Google Cloud URL]"
                         data-auto_prompt="false">
                    </div>

                    <div class="g_id_signin"
                         data-type="standard"
                         data-shape="rectangular"
                         data-theme="filled_blue"
                         data-text="signin_with"
                         data-size="medium"
                         data-logo_alignment="left"
                         data-width=300 >
                    </div>
                </form>

                <br/><br/><p><a href="">{% trans 'Forgotten your password?' %}</a></p>

            {% endif %} 

        </div>

    </div>

</body>


<!--Redirection if already Logged-In in cookies -->
{% if request.user.is_authenticated %}
<script type="text/javascript">
var csrftoken  = Cookies.get('csrftoken'); //using js.cookie.js

window.location = "{% url 'login_success' %}";

</script>
{% endif %}
</html> 

{% endblock %}
```

Im using a Django form to override the default `auth_views.LoginView` which returns to this HTML.

*Edit*
I came across a part of Google's documentation that addresses this [here](https://developers.google.com/identity/gsi/web/guides/verify-google-id-token), and the more I read it, I came to realise that their sample code might not be Javascript, but Python, so I inserted the entire sample into my source code.
Thing is....they're using webapp2, which I check is only compatible with *Python 2*, **NOT** Python 3, which is what Im using. So that's back to the drawing board.

Comment: This seems to be oauth2. Try to disable the csrf on the view where it redirects to your app

Comment: @bdbd Cant say I understand how to do so. Im not even sure where is the Google Sign-In redirecting to. The error seems to happen before it even hits my defined function.

Comment: You could try to disable "CSRF_COOKIE_SECURE=True" [CSRF configuration](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/settings/#csrf-cookie-secure), this one tries to connect as HTTPS connection.

Comment: @NadiaEspinosa I checked my settings.py: the documentation says it's set to ```False``` by default and I didnt include it at all in the first place.

Comment: Javascript code "var csrftoken  = Cookies.get('csrftoken'); " what are you using this for, do you need it, you do not appear to be using this anywhere in you code, have you tried removing this line of code form your script ?

Comment: @MikeMoy I get the `Forbidden CSRF error` regardless with or without the code. It was added to try and solve the issue in the first place.

Comment: Set the USERAGENT same as the latest Google Chrome Browser